# How to implement conditional looping and random selection in Lua

Tags: loops, variables, random, lua, conditional-statements

I would like to fetch a random record (using two APIs) which has an image and display it to the users. Besides, as the fetched record contains different values, I would like to use them later repeatedly across different Lua files.

In the code below, `value.original.source` is the image URL (in the 2nd API call) and can be empty (nil) in a record, so I think I need to keep fetching records, while it is empty (using `repeat-until` or `while-do`?). Maybe I need to use global variables to pass the data to different files, but not sure. It is tricky and challenging. Any ideas and solutions (of a part or whole) are highly appreciated. Thank you!

```
--Create empty tables
t = {}
t2 = {}

-- 1st API call
local json = require( "json" )
local function getWikipediaData( event )
    local res = json.prettify( event.response )
    local decoded = json.decode( res )  
    for key, value in pairs(decoded.results.bindings) do 
        local pname = value.person_name.value
        local dbpuri = value.person.value
        -- Put data into a table 
        t["PNAME"] = pname
        t["DBPURI"] = dbpuri
        -- Print key-value
        for key,value in pairs(t) do 
            print(key,value) 
        end
        local wikititle = string.gsub(dbpuri, "http://dbpedia.org/resource/", "")
        print (wikititle)

        -- 2nd API call in which a function is nested
        network.request(
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageimages&format=json&piprop=original&titles="..wikititle,"GET",
        function(event) 
            local res2 = json.prettify( event.response )
            local decoded2 = json.decode( res2 )
            -- This part is the tricky part I have problems. "value.original.source" can be empty (nil) in a record, so I would like to keep fetching records, while it is empty. Then, among the fetched records (with value.original.source in them), finally I would like to select one record randomly. The data in the record (in a variable) should be passed to other files.
            while (pickdata == nil) do
                -- Next level to "pages" is array, so for is used to repeat fetching data
                for key, value in pairs(decoded2.query.pages) do 
                    -- Put data into a table
                    local source = value.original.source
                    table.insert(t2, source)
                end
            end
        end,params)
    end
end

-- This is the second task to try to randomnly select a record with an image from the table created, but does not work. Looping and local vs global variables are the issues to be resolved.
local pick = math.random(3)
local pickdata = t2[pick]
print (pickdata)

local headers = {}
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
local body = ""
local params = {}
params.headers = headers
params.body = body
network.request("https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select+*%0D%0Awhere+{%3Fperson+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Fperson_name+%3B+rdf%3Atype+%3Ftype+%3B+dbo%3AbirthDate+%3Fbirthdate+.%0D%0A++++bind(rand(1+%2B+strlen(str(%3Fperson))*0)+as+%3Frid)%0D%0AFILTER+regex(%3Ftype%2C+%22Person%22)%0D%0A}+order+by+%3Frid%0D%0ALIMIT+10&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&format=json", "GET", networkListener, params)
```

Comment: It's not clear what problem you are facing. You should explain what your code is supposed to do and what it does instead. not just formulate some task and post some code.

Comment: The program seems to be correct.  Just replace `local pick = math.random(3)` with `local pick = math.random(#t2)`

Comment: Thank you @Piglet. I understand. Problem is it is not v easy to explain in writing. So I try again. What I ultimately would like to do is to fetch a random record (using two APIs) which has an image and display it to the users. Besides, as the fetched record contains different values, I would like to use them later repeatedly across different Lua files. The image URL is in `value.original.source` in the 2nd API call and can be nil. Currently that causes complains in the code (although such errors are not a problem and can be ingnored to achieve the above-mentioned task).

Comment: I think my task can be done with `repeat-until`, or `while-do` to in the right position to fetch only records with image, and, with `math.random` to randomly select a record out of them. Maybe global variables are needed to pass the values of the record to other Lua files, but I think I struggle to find a solution. If you still don't understand, please let me know! Many thanks.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, # is a good idea. I didn't know it. Cheers!